# Is the scattering length definitely positive if the potential is everywhere nonnegative?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, scattering

Is the [scattering length](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scattering_length) definitely positive if the potential is everywhere nonnegative?

Intuitively, it seems reasonable.

Any rigorous proof?

Comment: What would negative scattering length mean?

Comment: @Floris - a negative scattering length is quite common. It means that the phase shift in low energy scattering is negative ("pulled in").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, a potential that is nowhere negative must necessarily have a non-negative scattering length. This follows from the Riccatti equation describing the relationship between scattering lengths for potentials with variable cut-off ranges. The book "*Variable phase method approach to potential scattering*" by Calogero gives all details needed.

Physically what this means is that in the low energy limit, any non-negative potential can be replaced by a hard sphere (with radius equal to the scattering length of the potential).