# What is physical explanation of a scattering length?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, condensed-matter, scattering

Could someone please explain the physical meaning of a scattering length? I can not find a satisfying answer.

1. From what I understand, if the scattering length is positive, the bigger it is, the stronger repulsion is for particles?
2. Or is it like an imaginary sphere around particle where the sphere's radius is equal to scattering length and effectively this imaginary sphere behaves like a hard particle which can collide with other imaginary spheres?

For convenience I have drawn a little picture of what I described above:[image]

Comment: You mean "intuitive"? As your picture captures, it is an [effective radius for the potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scattering_length), so the scattering cross section amounts to dark disc scattering with  a radius of that length; a cartoon summary of the effective short-range interaction.

Comment: Near [duplicate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/143705/is-the-scattering-length-definitely-positive-if-the-potential-is-everywhere-nonn).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your second point is a nice physical picture in thinking about it. But it doesn't get to the repulsive/attractive interactions for positive/negative scattering lengths.

A helpful way to understand that is by considering square well potentials of length $L$ (ranges from $r=0$ to $r=L$) and strength $V_0$. The scattering length in this case corresponds to the position where the wavefunction turns and is 'pushed' out of the potential well.

If $V_0$ is positive and infinite, scattering length is $+L$, since it corresponds to a hard wall and the wavefunction is pushed out, right at $+L$. For non-infinite but positive potentials, the wavefunction is 'pushed' out at a length smaller than $+L$. This corresponds to a scattering length $a$, where $0<a<L$. A weaker potential allows you to probe more regions inside the potential, the limiting case being zero scattering length when $V_0=0$.

For $V_0<0$, an attractive potential, the wavefunction is 'pushed' out at negative values of $r$ (negative scattering length), which basically corresponds to the wavefunction being 'pulled' in all the way.